# What will a scale read when an object is released in water in a sink on it?

Tags: buoyancy

An object less denser than water is submerged in water in a sink and tied to the bottom of the sink with a string. The sink is on a scale.

If the string is cut, what will the reading on the scale be at that moment?

By thinking, I came up with contradictory conclusions.

- I thought that after the string is cut, the object will move upwards. The space below it will be replaced with water. Thus the system will have a downwards acceleration. Thus the reading on the scale will be less than the initial one.
- I also thought that before the string is cut, it exerts an upwards force to the sink. When it's cut, that force will disappear. But the sink can't move, so the scale will exert more upwards force to it. Thus the reading on the scale will be greater than the initial one.

Please tell me which one is wrong and how.

Comment: I think that when the object starts moving up the sinking water should transmit momentum to the scale. This should read more for a while then regain the initial value